# NullPointerException on same line no matter how I change code

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So I am getting a NullPointerException on the same line of code no matter how I change it. Even if I put a blank line there is still the same error on same line. Has anyone else had this happen? I'm pretty confused as to what could cause this.

edit: Should have mentioned I wasn't planning on posting my hundreds of lines of code as the error is always on line 317. Just trying to figure out if anyone else has had a similar problem and what the cause was. Also yes I have checked that I am debugging and running correct code.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: We need more info... show us some code ! Where is null pointer exception being thrown ?

Comment: Maybe you should recompile the code.  And make sure that you're executing the .class from that recompile, and not one hiding somewhere else.

Comment: Simon as I said it is always on the same line no matter what is there.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you David I'll read it! I didn't want to be another person posting their entire project, asking why it didn't compile. I figured I'd try to learn by finding it myself, with the help of someone pointing me in the right direction, which they did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like there is an issue with your environment. I would step back and make sure you are running or debugging the code you think you are.

Comment: Indeed.  Add something to create output well before the problematic code and make sure that gets generated when it is run.  Likely a stale build is being run, perhaps because the changes have introduced errors preventing compilation of a new one, or a different copy of the project is being edited, or...

Comment: It was the environment, which I'm trying out a new one. I created new project, threw everything in, and blam! Should have tried that to begin with I guess. Thanks!